# Set the column width of the exported Excel file

Tags: excel, width, alasql

I am trying to figure out the syntax of using Alasql to specify the column width for an Excel file. I tried something like:

```
var mystyle = {
    headers:true,
    column: {width:"300px"}
};
```

but it didn't work.

Is Alasql capable of doing this and if so, what's the correct syntax to specify it?

Also I would like to know the syntax to specify the column width for some selected columns, for example only the second column should have width of 400px.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which column that width belongs to.

```
var mystyle = {
    headers:true,
    columns: [{columnid: 'FirstName', width:300},{columnid: 'LastName', width:300}]
};
```

See working example from owner(had to fixed library reference): http://jsfiddle.net/95j0txwx/2427/